# Transforming a second-order ODE with nonconstant coefficients into one with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE

$$xy''+2y'+\omega x^{-3}y=0$$

By using the substitution $$\xi =\frac{1}{x} \rightarrow \frac{d\xi}{dx}=\frac{-1}{x^2}$$

We get a new differential equation in $y$ and $\xi$. We have

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d\xi}.\frac{d\xi}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d\xi}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

and

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{d\xi}\left[\frac{dy}{d\xi}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right]\frac{d\xi}{dx}=\left[-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2y}{d{\xi}^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right]\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Substituting into the original ODE (I have already multiplied by $x^3$ throughout), I get

$$\frac{d^2y}{d{\xi}^2}-\frac{2}{x}\frac{dy}{d\xi}-2x\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\omega y=0$$

Eliminating $x$:

$$\frac{d^2y}{d{\xi}^2}-2\xi \frac{dy}{d\xi}-\frac{2}{\xi}\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\omega y=0$$

BUT I am supposed to get

$$\frac{d^2y}{d{\xi}^2}+\omega y=0$$

as  per the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen copy below shows exactly where the mistake is :

[image]

Comment: Wonderful format to show the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is not right.

Rather,

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-x^{-2}\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right)=2x^{-3}\frac{dy}{d\xi}-x^{-2}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{d\xi}=2x^{-3}\frac{dy}{d\xi}-x^{-2}\frac{dy^2}{d\xi^2}(-x^{-2})$$

Substituting, we get

$$x\left(2x^{-3}\frac{dy}{d\xi}+x^{-4}\frac{dy^2}{d\xi^2}\right)+2\left(-x^{-2}\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right)+\omega x^{-3}y=0$$

Multiplying by $x^3$ gives

$$2x\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\frac{dy^2}{d\xi^2}-2x\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\omega y=0$$

and your result follows.

Comment: In general, $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{d\xi}\frac{d\xi}{dx})=(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{d\xi})\frac{d\xi}{dx}+\frac{dy}{d\xi}(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d\xi}{dx})=(\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}\frac{d\xi}{dx})\frac{d\xi}{dx}+\frac{dy}{d\xi}(\frac{d^2\xi}{dx^2})$.